# Understanding how to sleep/wait in a QThread without freezing the event loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety

Looking around I found mainly 3 proposals to sleep a QThread without blocking the event loop. But I don't know which one is the most efficient or if I should use one or the other depending of the circumstances.

Can someone explain me what is going on in each one? Is there any other proposal?

**ClassB.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QtCore>
#include <QWaitCondition>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

class ClassB : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ClassB()
    {
        qDebug() << "ClassB::ClassB";

        _timer = new QTimer(this);
        _timer->setInterval(100);
        QObject::connect(_timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this]() { emit continousSignalToClassA(); });
        _timer->start();
    }

    void start()
    {
        qDebug() << "ClassB::start";
        while(true)
        {
            switch (3)
            {
            case 1:
            {
                QThread::msleep(200);
                QCoreApplication::processEvents();
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                QEventLoop loop;
                QTimer::singleShot(200, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
                loop.exec();
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                QWaitCondition w;
                QMutex mutex;
                mutex.lock();
                w.wait(&mutex, 200);
                mutex.unlock();
                QCoreApplication::processEvents();
                break;
            }
            }
            qDebug() << "waiting";
        }
    }

signals:
    void continousSignalToClassA();

private:
    QTimer* _timer;
};
```

**ClassA.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QThread>
#include <ClassB.h>

class ClassA : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ClassA() {}

    void launchClassBThread()
    {
        _classB = new ClassB();

        QObject::connect(this, &ClassA::startClassB, _classB, &ClassB::start);
        QObject::connect(_classB, &ClassB::continousSignalToClassA, this, &ClassA::signalReceived);

        QThread *thread = new QThread();
        _classB->moveToThread(thread);
        thread->start();
        emit startClassB();
    }
    void signalReceived()
    {
        qDebug() << "** I get a signal **";
    }

signals:
    void startClassB();

private:
    ClassB *_classB;
};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <ClassA.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    ClassA classA;
    classA.launchClassBThread();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sleep a QThread use `QThread::msleep(200);` and accept the fact that events are blocked. Using `QCoreApplication::processEvents();` is in most cases a bad idea and a design flaw.

If you want to execute a function every N seconds or milliseconds, use `QTimer::singleShot` and remove any self written loops. This is pretty much the same as QThread::sleep(N), it just doesn't block the event loop, unless you have expensive blocking code in the QTimer.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, in my particular case I am trying to configure a slow hardware. Then I have to send the parameters one by one waiting few seconds between them. This was blocking a signal that I was emitting just before I was starting the configuration.

Comment: Then I started to look for ways to sleep and try to understand what was going on. Can you please explain why QCoreApplication::processEvents()  is a bad solution? The self written loops are active waiting but are they so expensive?

Comment: Alberto: `processEvents()` is not how Qt was designed. It's rather a workaround for something. If you need an event loop, because you receive events then you should use the normal `QEventLoop::exec()`. You can use a `QTimer::singleShot` with 200, 300 and 500 ms for example to set a delay beetween function calls without the need to call `QThread::msleep` in the thread which blocks the event loop. This way your functions will be executed with a delay, which is in particular the same as sleeping the thread, but without negative side-effects.